# MS Partner Center Powershell Command

Tags: azure, microsoft-partnercenter-java

`Get-PartnerInvoiceLineItem` command is running for a long but no output is getting displayed

Command:

```
Get-PartnerInvoiceLineItem -BillingProvider OneTime -InvoiceId $InvoiceId -LineItemType 'UsageLineItems' -CurrencyCode INR
```

Comment: On which version of `PowerShell` are you trying ..!?Could you please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/partnercenter/get-partnerinvoice?view=partnercenterps-3.0, May it helps.

Comment: Powershell 4...Get-PartnerInvoice...This command is working...but  Get-PartnerInvoiceLineItem is not working...!